# Replace/Change all values of a particular column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe 'df' whose size will be different based on different inputs

```
df1
   
   MeanPosition  Segment Mean
1    Position1   AACCTT  -1.4
2    Position2   AACTCG  -1.2
3    Position3   GCTGAA  -1.1 
4    Position4   CGGACG  -1.5
5    Position5   AACGTA  -1.8
.
.
```

As per my requirement in analysis of a Biological data the first mean would appear in 8th position then the second one would be in 9th position. Hence, I want to change the values in the column MeanPosition until the last position and my desired outcome is

```
   MeanPosition  Segment Mean
1    Position8   AACCTT  -1.4
2    Position9   AACTCG  -1.2
3    Position10  GCTGAA  -1.1 
4    Position11  CGGACG  -1.5
5    Position12  AACGTA  -1.8
.
.
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What is the logic? Always start from `8`?

Comment: @sindri_baldur Actually in my actual biological data the mean is suppose to be at position8, postion9 and so on as per the segments hence this is the requirement

Comment: Maybe that simple: `library(dplyr) df %>% 
  mutate(MeanPosition = paste0("Position", row_number()+7))`

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `lead()`, but then you will have NA's and the end of your dataframe..

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(MeanPosition = dplyr::lead((MeanPosition), 7))
```

Output:

```
   MeanPosition Segment Mean
1     Position8  AACCTT -1.4
2     Position9  AACTCG -1.2
3    Position10  GCTGAA -1.1
4    Position11  CGGACG -1.5
5    Position12  AACGTA -1.8
6          <NA>  AACGTA -1.8
7          <NA>  AACGTA -1.8
8          <NA>  AACGTA -1.8
9          <NA>  AACGTA -1.8
10         <NA>  AACGTA -1.8
11         <NA>  AACGTA -1.8
12         <NA>  AACGTA -1.8
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "   MeanPosition  Segment Mean
1    Position1   AACCTT  -1.4
2    Position2   AACTCG  -1.2
3    Position3   GCTGAA  -1.1 
4    Position4   CGGACG  -1.5
5    Position5   AACGTA  -1.8
6    Position6   AACGTA  -1.8
7    Position7   AACGTA  -1.8
8    Position8   AACGTA  -1.8
9    Position9   AACGTA  -1.8
10   Position10   AACGTA  -1.8
11   Position11   AACGTA  -1.8
12   Position12   AACGTA  -1.8
                 ", h = T)
```

Comment: Is there any way to substitute the `<NA>` values with subsequent 'position' s?